# How do I upload a file in Django OneToOne Model's FileField using form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-file-upload

I have one model `Detail` which has `OneToOne` relation with default `User` Model. I have a field `FileField` in my `Detail` model, where I want to upload the files using forms from frontend/templates.

I have been working around it a lot but I am not getting it done. I need help, please.

My **`models.py`** is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name="CSV File", upload_to='csv_files/')
    file_desc = models.TextField("CSV File Description")

    def __str__(self):
        return ("{} ({} {})".format(self.user.email, self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name))
```

My **`forms.py`** is:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Detail

class DetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        fields = ['file', 'file_desc']
```

My **`views.py`** is:

```
from django.views import View

class UserAPI(View):
    template_name = 'accounts/user.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = DetailForm(instance=request.user)

        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = DetailForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('user')

        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

and my **`user.html (template)`** is:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Every time I go to `localhost:8000/user` and fill the form and click on Submit Button, it gives me following error on frontend:
`No File Chosen`
and also the following statement appears above the File Selection Button:
`This field is required`.

I shall appreciate for the help. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

**`urls.py`**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register', RegisterAPIHTML.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login', LoginAPIHTML.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('user', UserAPI.as_view(), name='user'),
    path('logout', LogoutAPI.as_view(), name='logout'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**`settings.py`**

```
STATIC_ROOT  =   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Make sure your form tag is as follows: `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Thank you @raphael I did that what you said and I even added `instance=request.user` in this line `form = DetailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` in the `post()` method of `UserAPI` class, now it does not show errors, but it also does not do anything else, I checked the `Detail` table in admin interface and it was empty.

Comment: Hi @raphael I added `print(form.errors)` in the `else` block of the `if` statement that is checking the validity of form. But nothing is printed on the console except `[04/Apr/2022 19:40:00] "GET /user HTTP/1.1" 200 602`. Also I added `print('Success')` statement before the `if form.is_valid()` to see if I am successfully executing to the if statement, and that is also not printed. P.S. I changed `instance=request.user` to `initial={'user': request.user}` but still all in vain, no errors printed, no 'Success' printed.

Comment: Give `/` at the end of your folder path that is `upload_to="csv_files/"`, as stated in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield

Comment: Hi @SunderamDubey I added `/` at the end of `upload_to="csv_files/"` in `Detail` model, but no change, the behaviour is same as I described in my earlier comments.

Comment: Are you not able to find your uploaded file in the `csv_files` folder, is that your issue?

Comment: Answer to you question is yes, @SunderamDubey, but its more than that, I am not even seeing any record in `Detail` Table as well, a record should have the `user`, `file`, and `file_desc`.

Comment: You need to use `CreateView` rather than `View`.

Comment: I changed the `View` to `CeateView`, but no changes in behaviour.

Comment: Update the full traceback including `urls.py`  and `settings.py`.

Comment: PLease check my question @SunderamDubey. I have added the update as you said, but there is no `Traceback` error in console and frontend, actually there is no error at all, just the file would not get uploaded.

Comment: Can you update the question to show how the code looks now. I am having trouble seeing how are you passing the user instance to the form.

Comment: Hi @vinkomlacic I just updated the code, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your form is not saving anything because the line with `form.is_valid()` returns `False`.

You won't see anything in the `form.errors` because that attribute only shows field errors, not non-field errors. The non-field error in this case is that the required field `user` is missing. This is because you haven't specified it in the model form (also why it gets placed as a non-field error).

Also, you're not rendering the non-field errors in the HTML which is why you don't see them in your page after the post submission. I suggest using `crispy-forms` package (here's the [link](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). It handles things like form rendering out of the box.

Moreover, specifying argument `ìnstance=request.user` is incorrect because if you have a `DetailForm` the instance should be a model instance of the `Detail` model, not `User` model. Keep in mind, `instance` kwarg is only necessary if you want to use this form for updating.

I suggest an implementation similar to the following:

**forms.py**

```py
class DetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        fields = ['user', 'file', 'file_desc']

        widgets = {
            # I'm guessing you don't want to see the User field
            'user': HiddenInput()
        }
```

Relevant part of **views.py**

```py
def get(self, request):
    form = DetailForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)

def post(self, request):
    form = DetailForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial={'user': request.user.id})
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('user')


    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

To make this a complete answer, I will include a comment from [@raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10951070/raphael) which fixed the first issue of your code:

> Make sure your form tag is as follows:
> `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

**Some resources to follow:**

- [Form and field validations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/)
- [Creating forms from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)